# Bootstrap 4 not updating onclick attribute of popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popover

I am trying to create a popover in bootstrap 4 with a nested button inside it, but on updating the `data-content` attribute of that popover with the button element it updates this element, but the `onclick` attribute is missing.

I have tried using `button` instead of `anchor` tag, also tried using plain JavaScript to update the element, but the problem still persists.

I already have set popover property `html: true`.

This is the js code for update:

```
function popoverUpdate(cart){
    console.log("pop update");
    var popoverdata = "<ol>"
    for (i in cart){
        popoverdata +="<li>Item :" + i + ", Quantity : " + cart[i] + "</li>";
    }
    popoverdata += "</ol><a href='#' onclick='console.log(5);' class='btn btn-secondary'>Hello</a>";
    $('#cartVal').attr('data-content', popoverdata);
    $('#cartVal').popover('show');
}
```

HTML element whose `data-content` I am updating:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary m-lg-2" title="In Cart" id="cartVal" data-content="this is default content" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
      data-trigger="focus">Cart(0)</button>
```

Updated element as expected:

```
<a href='#' onclick='console.log(5);' class='btn btn-secondary'>Hello</a></pre>
```

Instead updates to:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Hello</a>
```

As you can see, the `onclick` attribute is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack. First, enable the data-html attribute, then you setup an event listener for clicks on your button, and finally prevent the default behavior

```
function popoverUpdate(cart){
    console.log("pop update");
    var popoverdata = "<ol>"
    for (i in cart){
        popoverdata +="<li>Item :" + i + ", Quantity : " + cart[i] + "</li>";
    }
    popoverdata += "</ol><a href='#' class='btn btn-secondary popoverButton'>Hello</a>";
    $('#cartVal').attr('data-html', true);
    $('#cartVal').attr('data-content', popoverdata);
    $('#cartVal').popover('show');
    document.querySelectorAll('.popover-body a.popoverButton').forEach((button, index) => button.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(5);
    //put the rest of your code here
    }));

}
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the response, I got your approach and yes it works quite well. However, I would still like to know the reason for this behaviour of popover because if in future i need to add more buttons with complex functionalities it would make it more complicated.

Comment: Well said, it's not a very practical solution as you add more buttons. Why the popover behaves this way, I don't know too, but please share if you figure it out.

Comment: Update: I found this answer. It may solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/57418074/11854340

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a ton, as I was using a very unconventional way to render that button, this is exactly the answer I was looking for...........Cheers!