# Can't display html in Bootstrap 3 popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page to test out a Bootstrap 3 popover and need to display html in the body.

Here is the html for the button that displays the popover and a hidden div that I use as a template for the popover body.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="status-add" type="button" data-toggle="popover">Add</button>
<div id="popover-content" class="hidden">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Room Status</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript to display the popover.  My apologies for the bad formatting, pasting it in as code doesn't work for some reason.

```
 $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

$('#status-add').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true,
    title: "Add new room status",
    content: function() {
        var html=$("#popover-content").html()
        console.log(html)
        return html
        },
    placement: 'right'
});
```

The popover is displayed with the correct title but the body is empty.  I can see from the console log that the html variable has the correct html in it.  I also tried setting the popover html setting to false which makes the html appear in the body as plain text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this, it's a bootstrap bug documented at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28290.  The solution is to include sanitize: false in the popover settings array.